# Running Apache Flink 1.12 Jobs on Apple M1 Silicon

Tags: java, apache-flink

I've just tried to run the [basic example for Apache Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/try-flink/local_installation.html) on an Apple Mac Pro with the new M1 Processor using the Rosetta 2 compatibility layer.

Unfortunately it failed with the following Stack Trace:

```sh
flink-1.12.2 ./bin/flink run ./examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
Executing WordCount example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/Users/muthmann/Development/Flink/flink-1.12.2/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.12.2.jar) to field java.lang.String.value
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute job 'Streaming WordCount'.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:366)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'Streaming WordCount'.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1918)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1782)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:349)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$7(RestClusterClient.java:400)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient$ClientHandler.exceptionCaught(RestClient.java:613)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerAdapter.java:92)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$1.fireExceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:143)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.exceptionCaught(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:231)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1377)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:302)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:281)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:907)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:125)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:174)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:386)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:376)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1019)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:233)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:253)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1133)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:350)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148)
```

So my question is, did anyone get this to run? Is there any chance of executing Flink jobs on Apple Silicon?

**Edit (13.04.2021)**
BTW.: This error occurs while running using the Rosetta compatibility layer. So that is unfortunately no solution to the problem at hand.

**Edit (14.04.2021 in response to answer from [Richard Deurwaarder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988324/richard-deurwaarder)**

I am running Java 11:

```
openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

**Edit (14.04.2021)**

This is the exception I get when running without the Rosetta 2 compatibility layer:

```
flink-1.12.2 ./bin/flink run ./examples/streaming/WordCount.jar
Executing WordCount example with default input data set.
Use --input to specify file input.
Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/Users/muthmann/Development/Flink/flink-1.12.2/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.12.2.jar) to field java.lang.String.value
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Failed to execute job 'Streaming WordCount'.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:366)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:219)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:812)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1054)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1132)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1132)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Failed to execute job 'Streaming WordCount'.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1918)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:135)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:76)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1782)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:349)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$7(RestClusterClient.java:400)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:970)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient$ClientHandler.channelInactive(RestClient.java:588)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.channelInactive(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregator.channelInactive(MessageAggregator.java:438)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:389)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:818)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$9(FutureUtils.java:386)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(CompletableFuture.java:376)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1019)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.ConnectionClosedException: Channel became inactive.
    ... 37 more
```

**Edit (15.04.2021)**

After starting the cluster, there is no Web Interface available under http://localhost:8081 (tried with Safari and Firefox).

Comment: This would be a good question for the flink-user mailing list. I know that support for the ARM architecture isn't all the way there yet -- see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13448 and http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/ARM-support-td42684.html -- but that's not really the same question.

Comment: I've posted the question here at first, to avoid the overhead of registering for the list and getting all those mails, where I can really contribute nothing, to my inbox. But the mailing list will be my next step of escalation. ;)

Comment: Did you have a cluster running? Those examples rely on having a session cluster available.

Comment: By the way, `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred` is not a problem -- this always warning always appears when Flink is run with Java 11.

Comment: I just double checked. The cluster was running. I get different exceptions, depending on whether I run using Rosetta 2 or not. I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok. The Exception now was a different one. Maybe the cluster was not running the first time. I've updated the question, with both exceptions. The one with Rosetta 2 and the one without. Both follow the three commands from the tutorial 'start-cluster', 'flink run' and 'stop-cluster'.

Comment: After starting the cluster, can you access the web ui at localhost:8081 ?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not. I've added that information to the question.

Comment: What do you see in the job manager and task manager logs?

Comment: I've provided TRACE logs to Robert Metzger via the Flink Mailing List. He believes the problem is with the REST interface used to deploy jobs to a Flink Cluster. That is why my jobs run from within the IDE. You can find the discussion here: http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Running-Apache-Flink-1-12-on-Apple-Silicon-M1-MacBook-Pro-td42923.html

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar issues with trying to run Flink on my M1 machine using JDK 11. As a workaround, I've been able to run Flink successfully in a Docker container by emulating Intel architecture without having to use Rosetta. To do this, you have to specify a platform of `linux/amd64` in your build config. [See this article on Docker's website for more info](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues).

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you are running with java 15/16?

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
```

I've seen other libraries struggling with some of the changes that happened regarding reflection and java 12+. This would also explain why the pipeline does run via intellij (as you've mentioned in the mailing list)

I would give it a try with java 11

Comment: That's a good point. Flink only supports Java 8 and Java 11 (and not all of the connector libraries have Java 11 support).

Comment: I am running: 

openjdk 11.0.10 2021-01-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.45+27-CA (build 11.0.10+9-LTS, mixed mode)

I have only installed that JDK so there should be no other Flink can use to run on.