# Cant build image for maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim for Flink client and Apple M1 core

Tags: docker, maven, apache-flink, apple-m1

I have Mac OS and macbook air with m1 core. I want to start docker-compose with flink playground (flink 13)  [docker-compose link](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/operations-playground/docker-compose.yaml)    from this docs - [operations playground](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/)

```
The docker-compose build executed with error
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim                                                                                          3.6s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/flink:1.13.1-scala_2.12-java8                                                                                        3.3s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:195e9c227ad891282e80602cac2372a3085ecf4ceefbb395558ffe0f7bb0b9aa: not found
ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build : Build failed
```

The docker file - [Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/Dockerfile)

Also I tried to execute

```
docker pull maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim
```

no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries

Then I tried to add to Dockerfile
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 maven:3.8-jdk-8-slim  AS builder
But there is an exception -

```
Type org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.HttpWagon$__sisu21 not present
```

And I tried to change the parent image in Dockerfile from  maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim to maven:3.8.2-jdk-11-slim or maven:3.8-jdk-8-slim. Build is OK, but after job starting kafka does not receive any message: the command did not show something:

Also I tried to change Flink version to 13.2 from pull request recommendation. But there is no result.

```
docker-compose exec kafka kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic input
```

I do not have the same problem with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some discussion of this in the Flink community, and on Stack Overflow. See [FLINK-22331](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-22331), [FLINK-13448](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-13448), and [Running Apache Flink 1.12 Jobs on Apple M1 Silicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67071254/running-apache-flink-1-12-jobs-on-apple-m1-silicon). There's work being done to prepare an arm64 binary release for Flink 1.14. See [the mailing list archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@flink.apache.org/msg44040.html).